# I received an error for my calculated field 'syntax error or is not supported

Tags: error, syntax

The following is the calculation that has worked on a number of SharePoint sites, but when I tried to enter it on a new site I got an error message .  Here is my calculation.  Can anyone help?  Does it matter that the site is in the Netherlands?

```
="<DIV style='font-size:12px; background-color:"&CHOOSE(Priority,"green","green","green","yellow","yellow","yellow","yellow","yellow","yellow","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red")&";'>"&Priority&"</DIV>"="<
```

Answer (score 1):

You are ending the calculation with `="<`, that would not be valid.